# увеличение значения переменной

Tags: javascript

Учу js, подскажите что происходит в цикле `while`?

```
var total = 0, count = 1;
while (count <= 10) {
total += count;
count += 1;
}
console.log(total);
```

Про `count++`  понятно, но что происходит с `total` непонятно.

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Если понятно, что происходит в ``count += 1;``, то должно быть понятно, что происходит в ``total += count;``.

Comment: @Эникейщик смотрите, про `count` понятно потому что это просто увеличение значения на 1 до 10, но про `total` можете словами написать описание как я с `count` сделал?

Comment: Могу. Это увеличение текущего значения ``total`` на текущее значение ``count``.

Comment: @Эникейщик то есть тоже просто увеличение значения переменной на 1?

Comment: Нет. Не на 1, а на ``count``. Добавьте console.log(total); внутрь цикла и все поймете.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока (`count` меньше или равен 10) {
  `total` прибавить `count`;
  `count` прибавить 1;
}

вывести(`total`);

т.е.

`total` = 0;
`count` = 1;

после `while` 
`total` = 1;
`count` = 2;

после `while`

`total` = 3;
`count` = 3;

и т.д.

Да простит меня народ за такое объяснение.

```js
var total = 0,
  count = 1;
while (count <= 10) {
  total += count;
  count += 1;
  console.log("TOTAL => ", total);
}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: понимаю, что слишком легко для вас:) но если не пойму сейчас не смогу продвинуться дальше. классно объяснили. Спасибо Вам.

Comment: @Timur, все мы начинали с малого, желаю успехов в начинаниях!

Comment: спасибо. не первый раз уже выручаете!:)